# Save time of day as number in mongodb, but display in a human format (using meteor autoform)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

In a form, I'm asking for a start time & end time, which I'll be using in a script later on.
I figured in MongoDB, a time of day is best stored as the # of seconds since midnight (per [How can I store time-of-day in MongoDB? As a string? Give arbitrary year/month/day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780415/how-can-i-store-time-of-day-in-mongodb-as-a-string-give-arbitrary-year-month-d)).

My question is: how can I display a human-readable time in autoform (e.g. 7:30pm) yet still save it as a number in mongodb & have proper client-side validation (make sure time is before 8:00pm)? I figure I could either use a datetime object & subtract the seconds since 1970, or I could parse the time string & do math on the hours, minutes, AM/PM.

Thoughts on methods? & where to put the math hooks in autoform? This seems like something folks a lot smarter than me have probably already figured out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date(<unixTimeStamp>)` will get you a javascript `Date` object which can be easily played with using libraries like moment (https://github.com/moment/moment)

Edit: also, to get the proper timestamp you can do `+Date.now()`. This jives with mongodb's date type

Comment: To elaborate on this, when you're inserting or updating the collection you can simply create a property and assign the current date as a date object, like `Items.insert({... startDate: new Date("12/12/2015 3:00am"), endDate: new Date("12/12/2015 10:33pm"})`, then you CAN use a library like moment to very easily format those date objects in to human readable strings, or you can use the Date object API to get things like `item.startTime = item.startDate.getHours() + ':' + item.startDate.getMinutes()`

Comment: Interesting, let me see if I understand. So even though I only want the time, I should save it as a date (with day probably hardcoded to 1/1/1970?) & then use the date API to extract the time?

Comment: yep! Much more robust solution than just saving the time.  You never know when you'll want the day too, and just saving time is a custom solution where there's already a standard