# Store only time in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I need to store in MongoDB just the time. The user types just the time, e.g. "05:20" as a string, and I need to convert and store this time.

Any tips?

I've been trying to use Date object, but with no success.

Comment: Possibly you have some source code to show?

Comment: What language are you using to take in user time?  What have you tried so far?  You have to give us something to work with to help you out.

Comment: tks for your attention guys. But i got the answer i needed. 
I'm using Angular in the front-end and nodeJs on the back-end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780415/how-can-i-store-time-of-day-in-mongodb-as-a-string-give-arbitrary-year-month-d

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you have two options:

1. Save time in `type: String`
2. Save date time in `type: Date`

But in second option you have to create Date object and set hours and minutes:

```
   const userInput = '05:20';
   const hours = userInput.slice(0, 2);
   const minutes = userInput.slice(3);

   const date = new Date(dateString);
   date.setHours(hours, minutes);
```

Comment: Man, your answer was amazing!! It solved my problem. Tks a lot!!!

Comment: is it work when we execute the where condition in query?

Comment: I was faced to this situation and found this post. I think another solution can be to store the HH:mm format as Number (800 for '08:00', 1800 as '6pm'). I think this will work for the 24 hours format but not for the 12 hours and also we can deal better with the query which I think is the main purpose.  ```const workingDaysSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    day: {type: Day},
    startTime: {type: Number, default: 800},
    endTime: {type: Number, default: 1800},
},{ _id : false });```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js library and store the time as number
`moment("1135","HHmm").format("HH:mm"); // equals 11:35`
or
`moment("135","HHmm").format("HH:mm"); // equals 01:35`