# MongoDB how to insert time format in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am using `mongod`b in my application to store data through nodejs . I have created a schema for a collection (to make it here easy I will call that collection `register` )  .Below is the structure of the collection' s schema  .

```
const register_schema = new Schema(
{

    arrived_at: { type: String }, // time  of arrival
    gone_at: { type: String }    // time of departure
   

}
```

);

I want just to save time in the arrived_at and gone_at fields in the format of 'HH-MM-SS'. Is it possible to store such data in mongodb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store only time in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798779/store-only-time-in-mongodb)

Comment: MongoDB does not have a time datatype.  They have a date datatype which stores both a date and time to the millisecond.  It is 64 bits in size.  If you store a string such as "13:42:17.552" this is 96 bits.  Maybe use the date datatype and disregard the date to save space?  Plus you get the added benefit of using built in comparison operators for date math.

Comment: ok thanks, it like mongodb does not have datetime data type @silencedogood

Answer (score 1):

There is no fine datatype for time handling or for adding specific time in mongodb schema except the timestamp. For adding time, just use string to specify the timing you want to add.